# Custom Model and fields with Sentinel / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, sentinel

I', integrating a new system to an existing database.

So, my User table doesn't have default fields names.

All names are in spanish, so, Sentinel looks for email when he should look for "correo"

Also, when executing

```
Sentinel::check(),
```

I get this message error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'administrador.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `administrador` where `administrador`.`id` = 1 and `administrador`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)
```

In fact, id doesn't exists, the PK is called administradorid

The only resource I found is a very quick one:

https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/wiki/Extending-Sentinel

It says it is extremly easy, but do not mention this case.

So, basically, how can I customize all the fields name of the Sentinel Model???

Here is my model:

```
class Administrador extends EloquentUser {

protected $table = 'administrador';
protected $fillable = [];
protected $guarded = ['administradorid'];
protected $hidden = ['contrasena', 'remember_token'];
use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `id` issue is a basic Laravel Eloquent issue. If the primary key for your model is not `id`, then you need to set the `$primaryKey` property on your model to the correct field name. Additionally, if your primary key is not an autoincrementing integer, then you need to set the `$incrementing` property to `false`, as well.

For the `email` issue, that is a Sentinel specific issue. The `EloquentUser` class has a `$loginNames` property that is set to an array of valid field names that contain user logins. The default is just `['email']`, so you need to override this property and change it to your field name.

So, your `Administrador` class ends up looking like:

```
class Administrador extends EloquentUser {
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'administrador';
    protected $primaryKey = 'administradorid';
    //public $incrementing = false; // only if primary key is not an autoinc int

    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $guarded = ['administradorid'];
    protected $hidden = ['contrasena', 'remember_token'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    // Sentinel overrides

    // array of fields that hold login names
    protected $loginNames = ['correo'];
}
```

Comment: You re rightttt my bad for pk... I ll try it monday and tell you! Tx!

Comment: it works. Next chapter, hash method is not the same-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407296/hash-password-compatibility-between-yii-php-crypt-and-laravel-sentines